# Swiper Slider Responsive background Image

Tags: css, swiper.js

I am using swiper for image slide and each div has a background image but how can I make the background images responsive?

Because when I resize the window the images looks like crop

Thanks.

THIS IS THE THEME WE BOUGHT:
https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/61311.html#gref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
    .swiper-slide {
        background-size: contain !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 50px !important;
    }
}
```

this will make the background image responsive. But I advise you to keep the settings like as it is. Because we can't edit the height of the slider so there is white gap between image and caption.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer @Sasith Did you view the template link?

Comment: yep. I did checked that.

Comment: Maybe I can search is it possile to edit the height ?

Comment: You have to edit the plugin files for that. Again I advise you don't do that. Considering this is a open-cart template, if you make mistake it'll mess everything up.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try this, and to get rid of repeating image or white bg, use background-size: cover ;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1170px){
.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover ! important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat ! important;
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
    height: 480px ! important;
}
.swiper-container{
    height: 600px;
}
}
```